# A block is sliding down without friction from the top of a hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problem is (as I suppose) well-known.

A block is sliding down from the top of the hemisphere of radius $R$ without friction.

We have to find the height $H$ at which block will be no longer connected to the hemisphere. I have to find it without using the law of conservation of energy.

While moving down, block's velocity $v$ is growing. So the centripetal force does also grow. Which means that, to keep the block on the hemisphere we have to "push" it harder against the surface.

Is it ok so far?

Now suppose, that the angle between horizontal axis and the radius (at height $H$) is $\alpha$. Which leads us to $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{H}{R}$.

The only force which pushes block to the hemisphere is $F_n = F_g \cdot \sin(\alpha)$ and this is decreasing while going down.

Is it correct to say, that the block will be no longer connected when the centripetal force $F_r = F_n$?

I am asking, because this thinking gave me correct answer.

$F_r = \frac{mv^2}{R}$, but velocity squared is connected to the height by the equation $v^2 = 2g\cdot (R-H)$.

Therefore,

$\frac{m\cdot 2g\cdot (R-H)}{R} = mg\cdot\frac{H}{R} \Rightarrow H = \frac{2}{3}R$.

Comment: You've used conservation of energy in your last step, is it required to avoid it?

Comment: This exercise is in the chapter about forces and Newtons principles, there is nothing about CoE. And I've only used the fact that Fn = Fr, nothing about the energy.

Comment: Your final equation connecting velocity to height is absolutely based on conservation of energy. You've just equated the change in kinetic energy with the change in gravitational potential energy and rearranged it to solve for v.

Comment: I mean okay, this equation of can be explained by the terms of energy, but since it is "banned" to talk about energy I had to formulate using only terms of force, and thats why I'm asking is it ok?

Comment: You have arrived at the correct answer. You did use conservation of energy. If the stipulation that you can't use conservation of energy only means you can't write the word "energy" it is a silly and pointless rule.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centripetal force arises from a definite trajectory of a particle, which is a circle. In other words, if a particle undergoes circular motion, even for a moment, there will be some centripetal force acting on it. To find the centripetal force we find all the radial forces and put them into a equation using Newton's Second law.

In your case, when the book leaves the hemisphere, which is at rest, the normal force on the book by the sphere will become zero.

Before that leaving position, the centripetal force was a vector sum of the normal force and the radial component of the weight of the book, but right at the moment when the book leaves the hemisphere, the centripetal force will only be due to the weight of the book.

This is exactly you have done and $F_{r}$ will give you the final tangential velocity along the hemisphere.

To find the speed you will have use integration. You know the distance travelled and you know how acceleration varies. Perhaps with some manipulation you will get the speed but I'm leaving this part to you.

Before answering your questions, lets see the correct equation for centripetal force.

$$F_{cp}=mg\sin{\theta}-N$$

Even though $F_{cp}$ looks like a decreasing function but $N$ decreases must faster than $mg\sin{\theta}$, that makes the $f_{cp}$ increasing.

Since, $mg\sin{\theta}$ is also a decreasing function, $N$ will have to decrease pretty fast to keep the centripetal acceleration increasing. And consequently, $N$ will become zero.

> While moving down, block's velocity v is growing. So the centripetal force does also grow. Which means that, to keep the block on the hemisphere we have to "push" it harder against the surface.

We don't have to do anything. There is no external agent if that's what you mean by 'we'. However, $F_{cp}$ will increase and the radial push on the book will increase.

> The only force which pushes block to the hemisphere is $F_n=Fg\sin{\alpha}$ and this is decreasing while going down.

This is not the correct equation for centripetal force. You didn't include normal force.

> Is it correct to say, that the block will be no longer connected when the centripetal force $F_r=F_n$ ?

Yes. That's a necessary step to get the answer.

Answer (score -1):

@Mitchell 's answer summarizes the correct response to the problem. But you are asking *"Is it correct so far?* and you should realize that your argument is incorrect.

As the block slides down, the required centripetal force needs to increase. But it's not that we push the block towards the hemisphere. Rather, a gravity component pulls the block towards the center.

The normal force opposes this centripetal force and ***reduces*** the radial force. The opposing normal force must gradually decrease until it becomes zero, at which time the block detaches.